# spring mvc use javascript to call and return data in this format

Tags: java, javascript, spring

I bought a website template and now I'm modify the template to suit my project.

one of my question is I have a JS function in the template is hardcoded data like below:

```
 var visitors = [
            ['02/2013', 1500],
            ['03/2013', 2600],
            ['04/2013', 1200],
            ['05/2013', 560],
            ['06/2013', 2000],
            ['07/2013', 2350],
            ['08/2013', 1500],
            ['09/2013', 50000],
            ['10/2013', 1300]
        ];
```

Question 1: How can I call the java code and return the result and suit to this format? Can I say above format is JSON?

Question 2: So I need to add the GET function into the JS function?

Comment: You have an array of arrays. You could access the cell holding the number 560 by referencing visitors[3][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) JSON is a set of key value pairs. For example

```
var DateJson={"MyArray":
[
        ["02/2013", 1500],
        ["03/2013", 2600],
        ["04/2013", 1200]
    ]};
```

Then you get the value of "MyArray" and get the desired value. To construct it in Java , you can use JSON API or you can do it manually as well. One of JSON documentation is here :-

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

2.) You can do GET to a URL that returns desired response.

```
$.ajax({
url:"myURL",
type:"GET",
success:function(msg){
    DateJson = msg;
},
dataType:"json"
});
```

The code that is there at myURL should construct the json that you need.